# How to change an endpoint address with XML Transformation in web.config?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xslt

I need change the address of this configuration in a web.config:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="OLD_ADDRESS"
    binding="basicHttpBinding"
    contract="Service.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
</client>
```

to this:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="NEW_ADDRESS"
    binding="basicHttpBinding"
    contract="Service.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
</client>
```

In my XML-Transformation file (it's working, it changes another `add key value`)
I have this:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <client>
    <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
      address="NEW_ADDRESS"
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </client>
```

but it doesn't work. I don't understand why it doesn't change, if I locate by name. 
Any help/tip will be preciated. Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Does the structure of your transformation file match your web.config? Specifically, are you missing a systems.serviceModel element?

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
   <system.serviceModel>
      <client>
         <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" address="NEW_ADDRESS"
           xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
      </client>
   </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```